# How do i get android to wait for text input?

Tags: android

```
    checkbutton.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    questionbox.setText("What is 2 + 2");
              if(answerbox.getText().equals("4")){
                  questionbox.setText("good job");
              }
              else {
                    questionbox.setText("nope");
                }
            }
    );
```

*Every time I run the program it automatically checks without waiting on user input, how would I be able to make it wait/allow the user to input some text before testing the user input *

Answer (score 1):

Move `questionbox.setText("What is 2 + 2");` to outside of `checkbox setOnClickListener`

```
  questionbox.setText("What is 2 + 2");
  checkbutton.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View v){

                  if(answerbox.getText().equals("4")){
                      questionbox.setText("good job");
                  }
                  else {
                        questionbox.setText("nope");
                    }
                }
        );
```

Then when you run the app first user can see the question content
After that, user can enter the answer
Then user tap on check button and you will test the result